# Porque algumas medalhas não podem mais ser obtidas?

Tags: suporte, medalhas

Estava stalkeando um moderador, e percebi que ele tinha uma medalha que não estava disponível para ser obtida por mim, eis a medalha:

> Aniversariante - Membro ativo por um ano, obtendo pelo menos uma
>   reputação de 200

Um stalk mais profundo me revelou que não é a única medalha que já não está mais disponível, existindo outras, como Pergunta Legal e Tagarela.

Também tem a Beta, mas esta não está mais disponível por motivos óbvios (participar do beta do site)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você só não tem os requisitos para elas ainda. A do aniversário é bem óbvia quanto a isso. Quando alcançar o que precisa recebê-la-ás.

Pode ser que o texto não esteja bem traduzido e dê a ideia que não pode.

A Analítico realmente foi retirada provavelmente porque não atendia bem o objetivo. Também não pode mais receber a Policial já que isto só ocorre uma vez no site, pelo menos pelas regras atuais.

Algumas na prática nunca serão recebidas por mais que se tente. E a ideia não é tentar todas.

Comment: Sim, mas lá naquela engrenagem de acompanhar medalhas, eu posso ver todas que são obtíveis, mesmo que eu não atenda aos requisitos. E essas que eu citei, não aparecem como obtíveis

Comment: Não pode ver todas, pode ver as que são interessantes mostrar para a pessoa acompanhar a evolução.

Comment: Aaaah entendo, muito obrigado